# Identifying dwellings/homes from imagery using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, remote-sensing, feature-extraction

I have a task where I need to identify dwellings/homes on property lots. The data that I have is an aerial image of the town, cadastre/property boundaries, land tenure information and land-use.

I was thinking using the land-use data to identify the residential areas and use those areas to select the cadastre/property boundaries (which may or may not have a dwelling/home on it).

What I am looking for is way to minimise residential properties that are vacant lots. Checking each lot manually will take forever so I am looking for some advice that could assist e.g. software that could detect a buildings from imagery or links to similar problems and solutions.

I am currently using ArcGIS 10.2.

Comment: This sounds like Feature Extraction so I have added a tag for that to your question.  Clicking on it will help filter questions to those that may be useful for you to review.

Comment: Good luck with that! You will need more data to accurately determine dwellings (LiDAR will work, infra red can also help) you can do a supervised classification to find areas that look like buildings but as roofing material differs in colour significantly you will need to do multiple iterations to find likely construction then trim down by area to remove 'noise' but really your data is insufficient for the task with any deal of accuracy. To incorporate LiDAR into this (classified or unclassified) be prepared to do a *lot* of coding.

Comment: which area the building footprints might be already captured.

Comment: @Mapperz - did you mean the location of the project? If so, its in Australia.

Comment: While there are methods to automatically extract buildings from imagery, and you could *assume* that homes only exist on residential classed lots, and further assume that there is only one house per lot (apartment buildings? condos?) and that the largest must be the house, there's pretty much no way to tell from imagery what a building is without making a lot of assumptions. I did photo interpretation for a couple of years. Without ancillary sources, what you describe is pretty much impossible. Is footprints your goal, or just vacant/not? Because that's usually in the property records.

Comment: Significant portions of Australia have building (points and polygons) with reasonable accuracy. In local government areas like Gold Coast I can attest the buildings (generated from LiDAR/Orthophotograpy) are less than 2 years old and are 99.9% accurate... I would contact your LGA and see what spatial data they have, if it's old at least you can reduce the parcels you need to look at - buildings don't often disappear but new ones are frequently built. @ChrisW, you could join development applications against lots to determine which ones *have* been built on - if you can get that from your LGA.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Here property records are typically kept at the county level and handled by an assessor (for taxation purposes of course, since that's the primary reason our governments care about property ownership). It varies on location and format, but somewhere in some assessor table or set of records there is almost always a vacant/improved attribute, if not specific details on how many, which, and how big a structure is on any given parcel. Because again, improvements mean higher value and more taxes. No need to consult development applications. Not sure how other countries work.

Comment: @ChrisW, it sounds like a similar setup, the Local Government cares as rates (land tax) get charged differently if the land is developed or not (depending on jurisdiction) so the local government handles that as they have a financial stake... any building that does not have a development application matching it is *illegal* and needs to be demolished. The biggest difficulty is getting your hands on that data, some areas agree with 'freedom of information' others don't want to share sensitive data - either way there is still potentially a nominal fee. RPData might have the info, at a cost

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson much appreciated for the input. I'll try and contact the Local Government regarding their spatial data and possible DA information. Failing having luck with them, the analysis will be done with some assumptions and caveats.

Comment: If you're in a rural or semi-rural area the CFS has buildings as points (for emergency evacuation purposes) but may not feel like sharing, Geoscience Australia has buildings (outside builtup areas) as points but is not accurate or recent - damn government cutbacks. Hopefully you can get some data to limit the number of blocks you need to physically check.

Comment: if you have a shape file of lots(many!) and if you have access to the building status of *many* of those lots and you have imagery, then you can start building an image classifier with one of the many deep learning toolkits available. It would take some programming, however. Start by making one image per lot based on the shapefile and use all the ones which you have information for as your training/validation set. If programming is not your thing, see nvidia "digits"..it may be useful. (or fun to try...I've used it but prefer Caffe instead)

Comment: Have a look at this post for a possible approach to creating building footprints - https://geonet.esri.com/thread/107721  It does require access to parcel data and/or building permit data to be really useful, but the results provide very good footprints.  I work for a local government, so I have access to both kinds of data for my jurisdiction.  We also have a website where this data can be downloaded, but not all jurisdictions do.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst A similar question has just been posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153799/extracting-building-footprints-using-ArcGIS  If you get a chance, an answer here summarizing your GeoNet solution, would let us resolve two Qs.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @RichardFairhurst:

> Have a look at this post for a possible approach to creating building
>   footprints - https://geonet.esri.com/thread/107721  It does require
>   access to parcel data and/or building permit data to be really useful,
>   but the results provide very good footprints.  I work for a local
>   government, so I have access to both kinds of data for my
>   jurisdiction.  We also have a website where this data can be
>   downloaded, but not all jurisdictions do.